# $\mathbb{R}[x]$ module generated by the following generators and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am trying to compute $$\langle a,b,c\mid xa=b,b=xc\rangle$$ as a module generated over $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (with relations).

Is the following result and working correct?

$$\begin{align}
\langle a,b,c\mid xa=b,b=xc\rangle&=\langle a,c\mid xa=xc\rangle\\
&=\langle a,a-c\mid x(a-c)=0\rangle\\
&=\mathbb{R}[x]\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)
\end{align}$$

where $(x)$ denotes the principal ideal generated by $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: Your calculations are alright.

Comment: @Moos: You are absolutely  right, serious brainfart on my end! I don't know what I was thinking.